# How I can remote to my ActiveDirectory Server with C# and Powershell Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, active-directory, remote-server

I must built a Webapplication that can add a new User in the ActiveDirectory about a powerhell command and I don't know how I can do this.

If I do this for the exchangeserver it works.

here my code for add contact in exchange Server:

```
string URL = "http://server141.test-company.com/PowerShell/";
string Schema ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";

public string CreateRemoteConnectionToExchange(string UserName, string Password, string Mailbox)
        {
                SecureString SecurePassword = new SecureString();

                string str_password = Password;
                string str_username = UserName;

                foreach (char x in str_password)
                {
                    SecurePassword.AppendChar(x);
                }

                PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(str_username, SecurePassword);

                WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(URL), Schema, cred);

                connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default;

                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

                PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                PSCommand command = new PSCommand();

                command.AddCommand("New-MailContact");
                command.AddParameter("ExternalEmailAddress", "SMTP:" + Mailbox + MailExtension);
                command.AddParameter("Name", Mailbox);
                command.AddParameter("Alias", Mailbox);
                command.AddParameter("FirstName", Mailbox);
                command.AddParameter("Initials", "");
                command.AddParameter("LastName", "");
                command.AddParameter("OrganizationalUnit", OrganizationalUnit);
                command.AddParameter("DomainController", configDC);

                powershell.Commands = command;

                try
                {
                    runspace.Open();

                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                    powershell.Invoke();


                    return "Der Kontakt wurde Erfolgreich erstellt";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ...

                }
                finally
                {
                    runspace.Dispose();
                    runspace = null;
                    powershell.Dispose();
                    powershell = null;
                }


        }
```

I donÄt know how I can make a Remote to the ActiveDirectory :/
I need the URL and the Schema String. The ActiveDirectory is on http://server137.linde-wiemann.com/ ? = OU=NPS,OU=services,DC=test-company,DC=com or LDAP://OU=NPS,OU=services,DC=test-company,DC=com

Can everyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I found this code about the active directory is this link it show almost all the functionality about the active directory.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C